# Is there a word for 'Simultaneously, but slower'?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

I am looking for a word to describe two events which occur at the same time and based on the same cause, but one event takes more time than the other to complete. I want to use this word for technical documentation of a process.

For example:

> The first module changes in response to a stimulus. The second module
>   changes [simultaneously, but slower].

Comment: I can't think of a single word to describe this, but in any case it's better make clear that while both modules *start changing* at the same time, the second module has a slower *rate of change*.  Which is to say that the actual process of change is not *simultaneous*.

Comment: I agree that there probably isn't a word for it, but I would change the current sentence to: The first module changes in response to a stimulus. The second module changes [simultaneously, but at a slower rate].

Comment: I think you are both right, as no one has come up with an answer. If either of you want to post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.